# Вывод названий вместо ID (JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql

Как в выводе всех заявок сделать что бы выводились не ID, а названия. С помощью JOIN конечно

### ***Надо вместо номеров (id) выводить названия, соответствующие каждому ID***

**Таблица хранения категорий и подкатегорий оборудования**

```
CREATE TABLE `selects` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;
```

**Таблица добавления заявок**

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `room` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deviceID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `defect` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'Ожидает рассмотрения',
  `date_completed` date NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Фактическая неисправность не описана',
  `regIP` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Вот как выглядит сейчас вывод - http://s41.radikal.ru/i094/1302/72/8e75aef6a756.png
А надо, что бы вместо ID выводились названия

- Таблица девайсов - http://s58.radikal.ru/i162/1302/13/3604a05217e7.png
- это добавление самой заявки - http://pastebin.com/yW915VG0
- это передача данных в БД - http://pastebin.com/Rr9cS4Xq
- а это вывод всех заявок - http://pastebin.com/WkwQZ47f

Comment: а в какой таблице хранятся сами неисправности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `applications`.*, `selects`.name AS deviceName
FROM `applications`

LEFT JOIN `selects`
ON `selects`.id = `applications`.deviceID

ORDER BY `applications`.id
```

К вашему выводу добавил JOIN и обозначил название устройства через поле deviceName, т.к. поле name уже используется в таблице `applications`.

Если надо отобразить только те заявки, которые имеют существующее устройство в табличке `selects`, то LEFT JOIN стоит заменить на INNER JOIN.

Хотя этот запрос можно было выполнить и без JOIN`a:

```
SELECT `applications`.*, `selects`.name AS deviceName
FROM `applications`, `selects`

WHERE `applications`.deviceID = `selects`.id OR `applications`.deviceID IS NULL
ORDER BY `applications`.id
```

Если нужны заявки, которые имеют существующее устройство в табличке selects, то условие `applications`.deviceID IS NULL необходимо убрать

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Но есть ещё один запрос, в котором тоже надо подключить вторую таблицу SELECTS, это страница "Статус заявки", я попробовал - не получилось...

Сам код - http://pastebin.com/XX3HiD7H

Comment: Так запрос почти идентичный, что мешает сделать так же?

Если что-то не получается, лучше в консоли MySQL все написать, и смотреть на что ругается.

Было бы лучше, если бы привели то, что не получается, а не то, что сделали, но вас это не устраивает. Исправлять ошибки так легче